# How to get unique data from 3 tables by matching some redundant fields?

Tags: sql

I've been learning SQL on my own and have an issue with this situation right now.

I have 3 tables,

- `SALES` (Item SKU, price, customer email,company name)
- `PRODUCTS` (Item SKU, Item name, Item type)
- `CUSTOMER` (customer email, name, department, address)

[image: sample data]

NOTE : "Item SKU" in SALES and PRODUCTS can have multiple instances of the same item.

I want to select all the different SKUs (not the repeated entries) from the table "PRODUCTS" and match each with "SALES" table to find all the sales for that products.

ALSO

Have to match the "customer email" from the table CUSTOMER and match it with the same from SALES and show the "department" and "address" of the customer.

AND

Display them if the "company name" in SALES matches with "ABC Company" and "DEF Company".

So far I've managed to get details from SALES and PRODUCTS but they include redundant SKUs depending on the company names and I did not connect the CUSTOMER table yet.

```
SELECT "SALES".*,"PRODUCT"."Item SKU"
FROM  "SALES"
JOIN "PRODUCT" ON "SALES"."Item SKU"  = "PRODUCT"."Item SKU"  
WHERE    "Company Name"  LIKE '%ABC Company%'
OR  "Company Name"  LIKE '%DEF Company%'
ORDER BY "PRODUCT"."Item SKU" ASC ;
```

So to summarize, I need to get the unique "Item SKU"s from PRODUCT and match with unique "Item SKU"s from SALES and display them along with the "customer email" "department" and "address" accordingly from CUSTOMER.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the (matching) expected result - as formatted text, no images.

Comment: @jarlh just added the sample data, sorry traveling right now so used notepad.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) (it's impossible to copy data from an image). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  You say that `products` has duplicate SKUs, but your data doesn't show any -- and such duplicates do not really make sense.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry, only SALES has multiple SKUs listed. Plus i can't edit it since you have reformatted it and my edit needs to be substantive (since the change is small).

Answer (score 0):

OK, these are not the prettiest but they should get the job(s) done:

`
    select distinct
        p.sku,
        p.name,
        ( select sum( price ) from sales where sku = p.sku )
    from
        products p
    where
        p.sku in ( select distinct sku from sales )
    order by
        1

```
select distinct
    p.sku,
    ( select sum( price ) from sales where sku = p.sku and email = c.email ) as total,
    c.name,
    c.email,
    c.department,
    c.address
from
    products p,
    sales s,
    customer c
where
    p.sku = s.sku and
    s.email = c.email
order by
   1, 3

select distinct
    c.name,
    c.department,
    c.address,
    s.sku,
    ( select sum( price ) from t_sales where sku = s.sku and email = s.email )
from
    customer c,
    sales s
where
    c.email = s.email
order by
    1, 2, 4
```

`